# Sidecar only shows a black screen on iPad until reboot

Tags: ipad, catalina, sidecar

It is 100% fixable by rebooting my Mac. It is also 100% annoying when I have to do that.
After the reboot I can use Sidecar wirelessly very reliably. Until I disconnect. Or change any Sidecar setting (Like: Show touch bar on/off). After that there is a good chance I have to reboot my Mac for it to work again.

1. Why does it do that?
2. How do I temporarily fix that? (Say: Is there a terminal command?)
3. How do I permanently fix that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found that if you go to display preferences -> arrangement -> tick and then untick mirror display option it will work but I would have to repeat this step every time I use sidecar :)

Comment: This seems to work for me, too. Hopefully, this will be fixed in the next update.

Comment: Works for me too, what a relief!

Comment: Genius, thanks for stopping me from pulling my hair out before I go bald

Comment: 100% the fix, stinks but better than nothing!

Comment: Seems like it's not working anymore on Monterey. Hate it.

Answer (score 2):

when you try to reconnect sidecar, you can click mirror display after connecting your iPad.After that, you will find your iPad get bright.Then canceling mirror operation.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle mirror displays on and off by pressing command-F1 twice.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have multiple displays connected (and one of them is iPad), toggling mirror off/on was not working for me. What helped was to disconnect other displays and then try toggling mirroring tricks when only the iPad is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this black screen problem with the wireless Sidecar connection. The iPad as an extended screen with a wireless connection started working well until it turned into a black screen today. Eventually, when the iPad is directly connected to the MacBook using the iPad charge USB cable it works well and the response speed of the iPad apparently becomes faster as well. You may need a USB adapter for your MacBook for this connection.

EDIT

Today after the iPad operation system is updated to a new version, the iPad as an extended screen with a wireless connection works well.